# Технологии современного геймдева

Tags: разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток!

Пока гуглю решил оставить вопрос здесь. Интересуют технологии современного геймдева, их возможности и востребованность.

Насколько ещё востребован в этом плане С++ ? На чем бы вы писали шутер, rpg или mmorpg? Можно ли использовать DirectX API из .NET ? Расскажите пожалуйста как можно больше о современном геймдеве!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Рекомендую обратить внимание на Unity3d. Очень активно развивающийся кроссплатформенный движок.

Comment: Текстуры, полигоны, карты нормалей, системы частиц, вертексные/пиксельные шейдеры, стрипы, индексы, матрицы, кватернионы, вектора, материалы, теневые объемы, атласы, карты высот, лайтмапы, камеры, фрустум куллинг, LOD, экспортеры мешей, компрессия геометрии, триангуляция, стенсильный буферы, буфер глубины, интерполяции сплайнами, хэширование клеток, костяная анимация, рельефное текстурирование, тесселяция, и.т.д. и.т.п(далеко неполный список) Этих "технологий" очень много их физически невозможно разъяснить в одном вопросе. Пишу 3D tower defence с видом сверху на С/С++.

Comment: [Рендер Diablo3. Как это работает](http://habrahabr.ru/post/157447/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[@Venje](/users/165/venje)](/users/165/venje), gamedev - дело очень неодноликое, ведь в это понятие входит и разработка простейших  двумерных игр, например, в канве( объект Canvas ) на HTML5 и разработка трехмерных игр со сложной физикой . Так, например, для разработки двумерных геймов вам будет достаточно обладать средним познанием технологий HTML, JavaScript и базовыми знаниями математики. Математика нужна везде, на ней весь мир вертится =) Так, например, при разработке практически любого более-менее серьезного графического приложения( игры ), вы довольно часто будете сталкиваться с задачами типа нахождения расстояния между двумя точками, движение по линии и т.д.

Вот тут я кое в чем не соглашусь с [[@savro](/users/8523/savro)](/users/8523/savro). Он говорит, что писать можно на чем угодно, "хоть на бейсике", но на самом деле это не так. Ведь писать, в таком случае можно даже и на ассемблере, вот только при этом вся ваша разработка будет постепенно превращаться в сущий ад: постоянная "борьба за захват областей памяти", утечки памяти, проблемы с извлечением данных из стека и т.д. Все это будет вас ужасно раздражать и отвлекать, желание что-то делать дальше при этом постоянно будет увядать...именно поэтому и создаются специальные 3D-движки, которые можно интегрировать и работать с ними через множество различных языков программирования.

Так, например, многие компании, разрабатывающие современные игры пользуются готовыми движками, которые даже, порой, созданы совершенно другими игровыми компаниями. В основном компании при разработке используют уже готовые объекты, готовые блоки, так сказать, из которых, собственно и происходит "постройка" игры. В итоге, вся суть разработки новой игры заключается в создании сюжета, создании образов персонажей, программировании меню и некотором низкоуровневом программировании под конкретную ОСь.

Comment: Стоит ли обратить внимание на язык С/С++ или лучше забыть про него и начать писать на чем-то более безболезненном, например .NET. Есть опыт разработки на Java. На С/С++ только для себя писал для самообучения. Какие возможности у каждого выбора и какие недостаки?

Comment: Писать стоит на том языке, который вы досконально знаете (со всеми его достоинствами и недостатками, а также "подводными камнями"). По скорости все эти языки уже примерно одинаковы - что с#, что Java, не сильно отстают по скорости от плюсов. А хреновый и медленный код можно написать и на ассемблере.
У "крестов" (C++) доволньо-таки много подводных камней, но если вы о них знаете, и знаете как можно из обойти, то можно вполне себе успешно писать и на C++. Берите то что Вам больше всего нравится, изучайте от корки до корки, и юзайте.

Comment: @Venje, отвечаю на ваш вопрос. Выбор языка программирование для разработки игр - дело второго эшелона. Главное - определиться с технологией, на которой планируется вести разработку. В C++ можно интегрировать практически любой игровой движок( Quake engine, Doom engine ), или же 3D движок(графическая либа)( OpenGL, Direct3D ). Поэтому, лично для себя в этом плане я выбираю C++, и даже не задумываюсь о поиске замены ему) ............... Идем далее. Вы можете выбрать для себя набор инструментов для крейтинга игр, например, XNA. Использовать его можно, например, из C#. Это, на мой взгляд, лучший..

Comment: ...выбор для новичков, вроде вас. Поэтому, я вам для начала рекомедовал бы пользоваться комбинацией XNA+С#. Затем вы можете плавно перейти на использование игрового движка Unity3D

Comment: @SoloMio, с вами не соглашусь. Не все языки работают одинаково быстро. Если брать, например, C# и ассемблер - земля и небо! Как вы знаете, приложения на C# выполняются не сами по себе, они "вертятся" на .NET платформе, а она в свою очередь добавляет много, порой лишнего asm-кода, что сказывается прямопропорционально на нагрузке на железо и, соответственно, обратнопропорционально на скорость.

Comment: Да, мне это все известно, но эта разница не столь велика, какой Вы можете ее представить. Благодаря успехам в разработке JIT-компиляторов эти языки становятся все быстрее и быстрее с каждым годом. А благодаря рефлексии на некоторых участках управляемые языки даже обгоняют нативные.
Проблема не в 2-3% процентах производителньости, которые вы выиграете, перейдя на ассемблер. Проблема в том, что практически экспоненциально вырастет время разработки и сложность разработки хорошей, быстрой программы. Вырастет настолько, что использовать ассемблер не будет никакого смысла абсолютно.

Comment: Тем не менее используется C++ или даже, скорее, ассемблер в "узких" местах, где все должно функционировать максимально быстро. Именно поэтому эти два языка( хотя асм трудно назвать языком...это, скорее, машинный хардкор) ) всегда будут использоваться.

Comment: @Francesco

> Если брать, например, C# и ассемблер - земля и небо!

Вы способны это доказать? Ну какими-то бенчмарками например? Это типичное заблуждение.

> а она в свою очередь добавляет много, порой лишнего asm-кода, что сказывается прямопропорционально на нагрузке на железо

Совсем не обязательно. Важно правильно раскидать обращения к памяти и писать с учётом кеша, а кол-во инструкций -- не сильно влияет.

Для того чтобы то что вы написали было правдой человек пишущий на ассемблере должен быть умнее чем JIT компилятор CLR, а это редкость.

Comment: > ассемблер в "узких" местах

Так писали лет 5 назад, сейчас так делают только для того чтобы выпендриться, но никак не по реальной необходимости.

Асм-вставки добавляют проблем с портируемостью, да и не дают воли компилятору сделать какие-то свои оптимизации.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev "человек пишущий на ассемблере должен быть умнее чем JIT компилятор CLR" -- ум тут ни причём. Масса рутинных вычислений и запоминания таймингов. И это в случае однопроцессорной/одноядерной обработки без учёта внутрипроцессорных оптимизаций.


"ассемблер в "узких" местах Так писали лет 5 назад," -- и раньше тоже. Актуально для чего-то достаточно мелкого (микроконтроллеры)

Answer (score 3):

геймдев это прежде всего понимание физики, математики и логики, а уже реализация в коде это дело пятое.
Если ты понимаешь 3 основополагающие вещи то хоть на Бейсике пиши.
Но если не понимаешь, то никакие даже самые навороченные технологии не помогут продвинутся дальше хеловорда.